# jQuery DataTables Ajax call is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I've got multiple data-tables and they all have their own ID.
Now this is no problem at all, the problem I'm having is that my code seems to be able to output my `console.log()` calls perfectly but in my *Network* tab I don't see my ajax call?

I'm using the following jQuery code:

```
function DtAjax(type) {
    console.log("Type: "+type);
    if($('#data-table_' + type + '_wrapper').children().length == 0){
        console.log("True");
        $('#data-table_' + type).DataTable({
            "ajax": "<?php echo base_url('admin/emails/ajax/get'); ?>" + "/" + type
        });
        console.log("End function");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    DtAjax(1);
    $("li .changeContent").on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevents going to a different URL

        // Content change
        $(".mailContent").hide('drop', 500).removeClass("active_div");
        $("." + $(this).attr('data-open')).delay(500).show('drop', 500).addClass("active_div");

        // button set new active
        $("#icon_nav_h > li.active").removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    });
});
```

It is logging everything inside the DtAjax function, any (obvious) reason why I cant find the Ajax call in my *Network* tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suspect this to be a `cache` problem :

```js
$('#data-table_' + type).DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: "<?php echo base_url('admin/emails/ajax/get'); ?>" + "/" + type,
    cache: false
  }
});
```

`cache` is `true` by default.

Comment: 1  simply best answer

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/apiRequest/api/get',
        success:function(data){
            var result = JSON.parse(data);
            var len = Object.keys(result).length;
            var newLen = len - 1;
            for(i = 0; i <= newLen; i++){

            $( "#alldata" ).append( "<tr><td>"+result[i].fullname +"</td><td>"+result[i].email +"</td> <td>"+result[i].phone +"</td><td>"+result[i].service_type +"</td><td>"+result[i].vehicle_type +"</td> <td>"+result[i].date_time +"</td><td>"+result[i].pick_location +"</td> <td>"+result[i].drop_location +"</td> </tr>" );
        }
          $('#example').DataTable();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My ajax wasnt working as well and i had one console error 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

So i added **success** function to make sure the response data is received and valid. Tracked the error location and i dont know why, but they for some reason added check of ***dataSrc*** option

I solved this problem just addin ***dataSrc*** option to ajax configs:

```
      ajax: {
        url: '/admin/api/modelType',

        // added onSuccess func to make sure the response data is valid
        success: (data) => {
          console.log('success', data)
        return data
        },

        dataSrc: ''
      }
}
```

**UPDATE**
i found out ***dataSrc*** is a key where the elements are located in response data, for example if a responce data directly containes elements array
`[{element: '1'}]` so leave it blanc ***dataSrc:''***

but if response body comes with :
`{content: [{element: '1'}]}`
here it's go

```
      ajax: {
        url: '/admin/api/modelType',
        dataSrc: 'content'
        }
      }
```